# Dynamically compute GitHub Action matrix

Tags: json, matrix, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to dynamically compute a JSON array of objects to pass to a matrix.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
  compute-matrix:
    name: Compute matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [get-environment-info]
    environment: ${{ needs.get-environment-info.outputs.environment }}
    outputs:
      matrix: steps.matrix.outputs.matrix

    steps:
      - name: Matrix
        if: github.event.inputs.build-all == 'false'
        id: matrix
        run: |
          echo '${{ env.BUILD_MATRIX }}' > build-matrix.json
          MATRIX=$(cat build-matrix.json | jq '[.[0]] | tostring')
          echo "matrix=$MATRIX" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Upload output
        uses: ./.github/actions/upload-artifact
        with:
          key: matrix
          value: ${{ steps.matrix.outcome == 'success' && steps.matrix.outputs.matrix || env.BUILD_MATRIX }}

      - name: Print
        run: |
          echo ${{ steps.matrix.outputs.matrix }}

  another-job:
    name: Another Job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [get-environment-info, compute-matrix]
    environment: ${{ needs.get-environment-info.outputs.environment }}
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        app: ${{ fromJSON(needs.compute-matrix.outputs.matrix) }}
```

`BUILD_MATRIX` is a values obtained from GitHub secrets and it's an array of objects as string. What I am trying to do is to create an array with just the first element when `build-all` input is `false`. The first element has to be always built.

The print and upload steps are just for debug purpose and when I download the output from `matrix` step, the content of the file is a valid JSON. I can download the artifact, open the file, copy and paste it in a website like https://jsonlint.com/ and it's a valid JSON.

But at the next job when I try to create a matrix from that output using `fromJSON` I get the error

```
Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'another-job'. .github/workflows/wf.yaml (Line: 775, Col: 14): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/wf.yaml (Line: 775, Col: 14): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,.github/workflows/wf.yaml (Line: 775, Col: 14): Unexpected value ''
```

Any idea about why I can't read the output of the computation?

EDIT:

The matrix is supposed to build multiple Android apps. So the original JSON contains information that I need to sign and configure the bundles:

```
[
    {
        "flavor": "app1",
        "packageName": "io.app1",
        "keyStoreBase64": "...",
        "keyStorePassword": "...",
        "keyStoreAlias": "io.app1-alias"
    },
    {
        "flavor": "app2",
        "packageName": "io.app2",
        "keyStoreBase64": "...",
        "keyStorePassword": "...",
        "keyStoreAlias": "io.app2-alias"
    }
]
```

And what I get from the artifact is

```
[
    {
        "flavor": "app1",
        "packageName": "io.app1",
        "keyStoreBase64": "...",
        "keyStorePassword": "...",
        "keyStoreAlias": "io.app1-alias"
    }
]
```

Syntactically the JSON is correct for me but I can't use in the subsequent job.

When I run the same commands locally it seems working.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a sample JSON in your question.

Comment: Hi @Azeem I added the original JSON to the original question

Comment: Hi! Just tested your scenario and it does result into the same error. Instead of `tostring`, simply using `-c` works fine i.e. `MATRIX=$(cat build-matrix.json | jq -c '[.[0]]')`. See https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5629294365.

Comment: Hi @Azeem! Thank you for reproducing our error in your repository. I tried your minimal solution in our repository and it works. Both jobs are successfully run. But when I try to restore the other parts of the workflow, I get the same error. After some debug I found out that is the `environment: ${{ needs.get-environment-info.outputs.environment }}` line on the first job to cause the error. Strange, because for the moment I am not even using anything environment related. The second job can have or not the environment set. It doesn't change the result of the execution.

Comment: Hi! You're welcome! Glad that you finally have it worked out. I can't say anything about `environment` though as `get-environment-info` job is not included in your question. Maybe, it's something to do with the actual value being assigned.